# How to disable default loading of Satellite DLLs (Language resource files) in a MFC project?

Tags: c++, mfc

MFC projects provide enhanced support for satellite dlls which generally helps in creating localized application with multiple resources. Those dlls are called as Saltellite dlls. When program is executed, MFC automatically loads the localized resource based on environment.

If MFC does not find any satellite DLLs, it uses whatever resources are contained in the application itself. I want to know if there is any configuration setting or any other way which can help stopping MFC to load any resource specific dll.

I know that MFC tries to load resource dlls and some other initialization stuff at entry point by calling method InitInstance(). If I do not call InitInstance method, I am observing MFC does not try to load any resource specific dll. Not sure if this is right way or is there Microsoft suggested way?

Comment: Not providing modules has the same observable effect as not loading modules. With that spelled out, what *problem* are you trying to solve?

Comment: @IInspectable I guess he/she is using the approach of using several DLLs, one for each language. And he may want to load only the English one.

Comment: @ser You get the effect by not providing any modules, and falling back to the resources compiled into the executable image.

Comment: @IInspectable, yeah I know. But may be is wanting to do avoid the loading programatically?

Comment: @IInspectable - I want to avoid loading of any kind of satellite dll. what if I simply rename any dll as satellite dll format, my code will try to load that dll as well which is not correct

Comment: This is still asking about your proposed solution. I'm not sure, what *problem* you are trying to solve.

Comment: @Ricky You could try to [`SetThreadUILanguage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-setthreaduilanguage) or [`SetThreadPreferredUILanguages`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-setthreadpreferreduilanguages) (Vista+) before calling the base `InitInstance`. Though it's still not clear why you'd build language DLLs to begin with, if you then go to great lengths just to avoid using them.

Comment: At the right moment you might be able to follow the advice of @dxiv, but at other times it might be too late. You can walk all the DLLs in your resource chain, and that includes the MFC core ones, and you could manually unload the DLLs and set the resource handle of each item in the DLL table to be the same as the DLL HINSTANCE.

Comment: I am not building any Language DLLs but somebody can use any random dll and just rename it as per the satellite dll format based on my exe name and try to load their dll using my exe. Its kind of security problem.